# double quotes inside single quotes in MYSQL result?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do something very basic but I can't figure out how.

basically i'm trying to convert the mysql result ($row) into the following format (literal strings):

```
"0784562627828" => "James",
"0786636363663" => "David",
```

I have all the data stored in the database and I can get them echoed on my page like so:

```
$phone = $row['phone'];
$name = $row['name'];
$list .=''.$phone.'';

echo $list;
```

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks

Comment: You can't try $a = array(); $a[$row['phone']] = $row['name']; ?

Comment: 3 answers and a comment all saying the same thing. pick one.

Comment: @Adelphia, and unfortunately none of them work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign them inside an array like you normally would:

```
$array = array();
while(your fetch here) {
    $array[$row['phone']] = $row['name'];
}
```

To check its contents, you can use `var_dump($array)` or `print_r($array)`

Or just straight up show them, like the one you formatted:

```
while(your fetch here) {
    echo '"' . $row['phone'] . '"' . ' => ' . '"' . $row['name'] . '"' . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: i thought this would work but echoing $array would display Array on my page!

Comment: @user3806613 That's why you think they're not working. You can't echo an array. use var_dump() instead. Every one of these solutions will work. they're all exactly the same.

Comment: @user3806613 you cannot outright `echo` an array. you can use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`

Comment: nice one. but that still is not the format that i mentioned in my question! i.e. it puts everything in () and also there is no double quotes around the name and phone number!

Comment: @user3806613 oh okay check my revision. and why are you shouting! lol!

Comment: :D +1 for making me giggle.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
$list = array(); 
$list[$phone] = $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like

```
$list = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $list[$row['phone']] = $row['name'];
}
```